# bash переименование

Tags: linux, файлы, bash

Не силен в bash. Есть директория с файлами, можно ли средствами linux добавить к именам файлов дату создания этих файлов?

Например:
`файл_дата_создания.jpg`

Answer (score 4):

Рекурсивно, начиная с текущего каталога заменить имя всех .jpg файлов на 
%оригинальное имя%_%дата модификации%

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -exec mv -fv {} $(dirname {})${$(basename {})%.*}_$(stat -c %y {} | cut -d ' ' -f1).jpg \;
```

Прошу быть аккуратнее, не портируемо на FreeBSD и не тестировано.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, только так:

```
mv файл.jpg файл_$(stat -c %y файл.jpg | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```

Дату можно получить так:

```
stat -c %y файл.jpg | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

А чтобы получить вывод одной команды как аргумент для другой, надо поместить ее в такие скобки:

```
$()
```

Answer (score 1):

Для нескольких файлов IMHO все равно надо скрипт писать. Что-то в таком духе

```
#!/bin/bash

cd tst
for i in *
do
    sfx=''
    tim=`stat -c %Y $i`
    dt=`date +_%d-%m-%y--%T --date=@$tim`
#    echo $i
    if echo $i | grep -sq '\.'  ; then
        sfx=`echo $i | sed 's/.*\.//'`
        base=`echo $i | sed s/$sfx\$// | sed 's/\.$//'`
#       echo sfx=$sfx  base=$base
    fi
    if [ "$sfx" == "" ] ; then
        echo mv $i ${i}$dt
    else
        echo mv $i $base$dt.$sfx
    fi
done
```

Вы посмотрите `man date` и подпрвьте форматы, как Вам будет удобней (ну и echo из `echo mv ...`, естественно, уберите).

Сейчас у меня тестовый вывод вот такой:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./rename.sh
mv a a_28-09-12--18:27:10
mv aaa.bbb.ccc aaa.bbb_20-05-15--13:57:58.ccc
mv f1 f1_28-09-12--16:40:19
mv f2 f2_28-09-12--16:40:19
mv f3 f3_28-09-12--16:40:19
mv f.txt f_28-09-12--18:49:25.txt
mv guessfrom.c guessfrom_24-09-12--00:08:13.c
mv libxaxa.so libxaxa_23-09-12--23:21:21.so
mv my-prog.tar my-prog_23-09-12--23:25:49.tar
mv prog prog_23-09-12--23:23:34
mv Readme.txt Readme_24-09-12--00:52:06.txt
mv rxaxa rxaxa_24-09-12--00:08:57
mv rxaxa.c rxaxa_23-09-12--23:52:25.c
mv txaxa.c txaxa_23-09-12--23:00:58.c
mv xaxa xaxa_23-09-12--23:21:55
mv xaxa.c xaxa_23-09-12--23:00:41.c
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Comment: (1)`tim=$(stat -c %Y $i); dt=$(date +_%d-%m-%y--%T --date=@$tim)` может сразу `tim=$(date +_%d-%m-%y--%T -r "$i")` (2)`base=${i%.*};sfx=${i#${i%.*}}` тогда проверки не нужны : `echo mv $i $base$dt$sfx` —> сводим к одной строке `for i in * ; do echo mv "$i" "${i%.*}$(date +_%d-%m-%y--%T -r "$i")${i#${i%.*}}" ; done`